# Export different ranges of two different sheets to one single PDF file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-pdf

i try to export a single PDF file from two different ranges of two different sheets.
i need a single print document (PDF) with two sites in landscape..

Site 1: Sheetname1 - Range A1:G17

Site 2: Sheetname2 - Range A1:M22

my code generate a PDF file from one range in a sheet to a folder in drive an send an email with this file attached to a list of receivers. But i have no idee how i export a two-sites pdf-file with two different ranges from two different sheets.

hope anyone can help me out...

greetings

```
var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var weighingsheet = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Weighing");
  var datasheet = activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Data");
      
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + activeSpreadSheet.getId() + "/export?"
  var params = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
    + '&portrait=false'
    + '&fitw=true'
    + '&top_margin=0.50'              
    + '&bottom_margin=0.50'          
    + '&left_margin=0.30'             
    + '&right_margin=0.30'
    + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'
    + '&vertical_alignment=MIDDLE'
    + '&gid=' + weighingsheet.getSheetId()
    + '&range=A1:G17';

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); 
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + params, { 
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });  

    var fileName = datasheet.getRange("Q14").getValue() + ".pdf";
    var theBlob = response.getBlob().setName(fileName);
    var folderID = "12345678901234567890";
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);

    folder.createFile(theBlob);
   
    MailApp.sendEmail(datasheet.getRange("M3").getValue() + ", " + datasheet.getRange("M4").getValue() + ", " + datasheet.getRange("M5").getValue() + ", " + datasheet.getRange("M6").getValue() + ", " + datasheet.getRange("M7").getValue() + ", " + datasheet.getRange("M8").getValue() + ", " + datasheet.getRange("M9").getValue() + ", " + datasheet.getRange("M10").getValue() + ", " + datasheet.getRange("M11").getValue() + ", " + datasheet.getRange("M12").getValue(),
      datasheet.getRange("Q3").getValue(), datasheet.getRange("Q4").getValue(), {attachments:[theBlob]});
```

Answer (score 1):

### As a workaround I'd use Class HTMLOutput

Here's my approach:

```
function test() {
  // Add spreadsheets as needed 
  var spreadsheetsToProcess = [
    {
      spreadsheetId: "ID_SPREADSHEET",
      sheetName: "SHEET NAME",
      rangeA1Notation: "A1:G17"
    },
    {
      spreadsheetId: "ID_SPREADSHEET",
      sheetName: "SHEET NAME",
      rangeA1Notation: "A1:M22"
    }
  ];

  var file = getPDF(spreadsheetsToProcess);

  MailApp.sendEmail("example@example.com", 'Attachment example', 'Two spreadsheets at once.', {attachments:[file]});
}

function getPDF(spreadsheets) {
  var html = "<h2>Example 2 ranges from different Spreadsheets</h2>";
  spreadsheets.forEach(spreadsheet => {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.spreadsheetId);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(spreadsheet.sheetName);
    var data = sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.rangeA1Notation).getValues();

    html += "<h3>Example</h3><table style='width:100%; border: 1px solid black'>";
    data.forEach(row => {
      html += "<tr style='border: 1px solid black'>";
      row.forEach(cell => {
        html += `<td style='border: 1px solid black'>${cell}</td>`;
      })
      html += "</tr>";
    });
    html += "</table><br/>";
  })

  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  var pdf = output.getAs('application/pdf').setName("export.pdf");

  return pdf;
}
```

You can easily adapt this code to yours where **test** will send the mail and **getPDF** will expect an array of objects which is composed by `spreadsheetId`, `sheetName` and `rangeA1Notation`. Class HTMLService will allow you to create an HTMLOutput from a string and then you can customize this as needed. Once you get this HTML you can convert it to a PDF by using [getAs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#getascontenttype) method which will return a Blob that you can send through MailApp.

Comment: Hey Jose, thank you for your answer... But i want the same layout and colour, font etc. settings like the sheet. Not a new adjustable html object. Is their a way to do that ?

Comment: When you referer to `Site 1: Sheetname1 - Range A1:G17` the Site 1 part means Spreadsheet 1?

Comment: that is good work from you @JoseVasquez but i have a question is there anyway to change  rangeA1Notation:  to be getRange instead of "A1:G17" so i can get the range by values from a cell?  thank you in advance